# Overall configuration object for a god object and late initialisation

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded

There are two main parts to this question: storing configuration values in a single file/place and delaying initialisation of a contained object.

## Storing configuration values

I have an embedded program which controls a PCB test fixture for a semi-automated test. I would like to store all of the limits/test parameters in a single place (preferably as read only/constants) so that they can be easily located and tweaked in the future. The problem is that some of the values are within nested structs and the only way that I know of initialising these objects is using the dreaded initialiser list where all traceability is lost (or a constructor which is almost as bad).

e.g.

```
class Configuration {

public:
  struct NestedStruct {
    float value1;
    float value2;
    float value3;
  };

  struct ContainerStruct {
    int value1;
    float value2;
    NestedStruct nested1;
    NestedStruct nested2;
    NestedStruct nested3;
    float value3;
  };

  // Initialise struct data member.
  // Not obvious which value is which?
  constexpr static const ContainerStruct containerStruct {5, 2.3, 1.4, 4.2, 0.7, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 4.6};

  // Slightly more readable
  constexpr static const ContainerStruct containerStruct {5, 2.3, {1.4, 4.2, 0.7}, {3.5, 2.5, 3.5}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.1}, 4.6};

};
```

How can I store read only configuration values made up of complex/nested struct values in one place while maintaining readability?

## Controller/god object initialisation

I've decided to wrap the core functionality into a single controller object that instantiates multiple contained objects. One of these objects is passed to some of the other objects via a pointer. I use the configuration values mentioned above (for which there are lots!) to initialise these objects.


Using an initialiser list makes the constructor of the Controller class long and untidy. One way I could get around this is by creating an empty constructor for the contained objects with a separate initialiser function which I could call in the body of the Controller's constructor.


However, I've always read that two step/ lazy initialisation is bad as the object isn't immediately usable. Is there another way around this?

Maybe there is a better way than wrapping it in a god object?

## Example parameters that I want to store in one place:

**Adc object parameters:**

```
float voltageReference;
uint8_t slaveSelectPin;
```

**NavigationButtons object parameters:**

```
struct AdcValues {
  uint_fast16_t buttonUp;
  uint_fast16_t buttonDown;
  uint_fast16_t buttonLeft;
  uint_fast16_t buttonRight;
  uint_fast16_t buttonCentre;
  uint_fast8_t tolerance;
};
```

**UutPower object parameters:**

```
struct CurrentCompensation {
  float LowX;
  float LowC;
  float MidX;
  float MidC;
  float HighX;
  float HighC;
};
```

**VoltageTests object parameters:**

```
struct TestParameter {
  float scalingFactor; // Potential divider scaling for voltages >voltageRef.
  float limitLower;
  float limitUpper;
  const char *signalName;
};

// Lots of nested structs.
struct TestParameters {
  TestParameter tb1_1;
  TestParameter tp15;
  TestParameter tp4;
  TestParameter tp1;
  TestParameter tp3;
  TestParameter tp20;
  TestParameter tp12;
  TestParameter tp29;
  TestParameter tp28;
  TestParameter con3_6;
  TestParameter con3_2;
}
```

**Other parameters:**

```
float currentLimitLow;
float currentLimitHigh;
const char *version;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is C an option? In C you could use designated initializers `constexpr static const ContainerStruct containerStruct = { .value1=5 }`.

Comment: It's using an Arduino with cut-down functionality of C++ standard libraries (C with classes I guess). Unfortunately the compiler doesn't accept this, nor the other standard with a colon `containerStruct = { value1:5 }`

Comment: I once had a very similar situation in a project. Embedded sys/microcontroller, huge amount of data in flash eeprom (64kb), all of it residing in a big monster struct. It still turned out quite well because I could use designated initializers. Without them I think it would have turned out quite ugly. One of the few uses I have found for designated initializers.

Comment: @Lundin I'm glad I'm not the only one to have come up against this problem! Hmmm, thinking more about it, there is no reason why I couldn't create a separate C source file for this. I misunderstood you before and thought you were talking about switching the whole project over to C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most feasible option is likely to split your structs into individual `const` variables, you'll have to group them by variable naming or something instead.

Once you have this, you alter your linker file to give every single variable a dedicated address. Or alternatively your compiler might have a non-standard extension for this, like the `@`operator.

This allows you to initialize every single such variable individually.

This is great for maintenance, since adding or removing variables won't change the addresses of other, non-related variables. Plan your memory map with great care and leave "holes" here and there, to allow future extensions. Consider alignment, if applicable (if you use some 8 bit crap MCU, this won't be an issue).

Another advantage of this is that you can localize `const` variables to the files where they are used, rather than keeping them in a global "monster struct".

Comment: Would you be able to point me to some further information on the @ operator (Google doesn't like the @ or at). I've not done any modification to linker files before (only started learning C++ and anything embedded related since January and no other experience with the lower level build process). This is using an 8 bit 'crappy' AVR Mega. I may just have to accept that there is no super elegant way of doing this. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: @mattb5906 You'll have to read your compiler manual to see how to allocate objects at a given address.